# Requested View Couldn't be restored

Tags: glassfish-3

I made a web application using (JSF and JPA) and then deployed it to Glassfish Application Server.

It works fine, but when I leave the Application idle for a period of time, maybe one hour, and then trying to use the application, it throws exception said that (the requested view couldn't be restored).

And when reloading my application in Glassfish it works fine again, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a ViewExpiredException and is fired when the state saving method is set to server(default) and you make a post request to the view which is not available in the session anymore.

One way to solve the problem is to redirect users to a particular page when this type of exception is thrown. You can configure an error page for this in web.xml.

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
<location>/errorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```